# Flatness of homomorphisms of graded-commutative rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, graded-modules, graded-rings

Algebraic geometry offers some properties and criteria for homomorphism of commutative rings to be flat. What about homomorphisms of graded-commutative rings? You can define flatness as usual: $R \to S$ is flat iff $S \otimes_R - : \mathsf{grMod}(R) \to \mathsf{grMod}(S)$ is exact. It turns out that this is equivalent to flatness of the underlying ring homomorphism (i.e. we may forget gradings; but the underlying rings will be non-commutative). What is some literature dealing with flatness of homomorphisms of graded-commutative rings?